# Help with resistor in gain and filter op-amps circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, filter, piezo, preamp

I'm designing a piezo preamp with high-pass filter using two preamps. The first one amplifies the signal, while the second one filters it (and some little extra gain). See schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f31qI9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is about R4. Is it needed? What value should it have? I read in one answer, that op-amps don't like to drive capacitors. What happens with or without R4? Another question, would I be able to reduce this to one op-amp if my input is a piezo? Or do I need the first one to buffer the high-impedance piezo signal as I've done now?

Comment: I might be inclined to make R3 10k or 100k, and adjust C1 to suit. R3=1k in this context feels just _wrong_. By the way, the second opamp is not a highpass filter, it's a buffer on your high pass filter of C1/R3. Look up Sallen-Key to see what a filter wrapped round an opamp looks like

Comment: Right, of course the second op-amp acts as a buffer. R3 is in fact a 10k pot (in series with 100 ohms) so I can vary the cutoff. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The op-amp won't be driving the capacitor even if R4 were zero ohms. The other side of the cap isn't hard-connected to a strong voltage source at all - the input impedance is Gohms and the only other component is the 1k to ground. It'll work with R4 = 0.

If you choose your op-amp to have the right gain-bandwidth product then one op-amp can do the job but you have to bias the input (ditto your original circuit) with maybe a 1 Mohm resistor across the piezo. It comes down to analysing the effect of input bias currents through the 1 Mohm and deciding maybe that a different op-amp might produce less output voltage offset at a certain gain.

Or, you can still do this with a flakier op-amp if you insert capacitors in series with R2 (or R6) - this makes the DC gain of each (or the only) stage unity so DC offset amplification is minimized.

Comment: Many thanks, Andy. Yes, I have a 1M resistor across the piezo. So is the gain achievable by an op-amp mostly limited by DC offset and the amplification thereof? When I install a cap in series with R2 and/or R6, how does that rid me of DC offset? Because DC is filtered out on the way to earth? Bear with me :))

Answer (score 1):

R4 is unnecessary. As "Andy aka" points out, OA1 is not driving a capacitor. The impedance at the output is kept relatively high by the 1 kΩ resistor (R3).

You could use a single op amp with an inductor in the feedback path to limit the gain at low frequencies.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEsB3F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, it looks like the gain can be limited at low frequencies just by loading the piezo electric transducer. You may want to consider simply loading it to reduce the gain at lower frequencies.
http://www.cafewalter.com/cafewalter/fetpre/pzp1_project.htm

Comment: thanks, actually I have a 1M resistor across the piezo earlier in the schematic! very much appreciated!